# casting variable as the function's returned class instance

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns one of classes instances.
What I want to do is to 're-cast' the variable as the returned value's actual type.

[typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=37&pc=1#)

```js
// classes
class Cake{
    myName: string;
    base: string = "vanilla"
    frosting: string = "empty"
    constructor(myName: string) {
        this.myName = myName
    }
}

class Chocolate extends Cake{
    frosting: string = "chocolate"
    cut() {
        console.log("cut to 8 pieces!")
    }
}

class Strawberry extends Cake {
    frosting:string="strawberry"
    topping:string="coconut"
}

// functions
function getCake(frosting:string, myName:string):Chocolate|Strawberry {
    const chocolateClass = new Chocolate(myName)
    const strawberryClass = new Strawberry(myName)
    const classes:any = { chocolateClass, strawberryClass }
    let returnedObj: Chocolate|Strawberry;
    Object.keys(classes).forEach((key) => {
        if (classes[key].frosting == frosting) {
            returnedObj = classes[key]
        }
    })
    return returnedObj
}

// logic
const myCake: Strawberry | Chocolate = getCake("chocolate", "John")
console.log(myCake.frosting)  // can access it
console.log(myCake.myName)  // can access it
myCake.cut() // can access it, but has linting error + can't see it through intellisense
```

I can access specific properties from the `strawberry` class,

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEu4B.png)

but my issue is that the linting says it doesn't exist even though it does. This also prevents intellisense from seeing `cut()`.

So I came to the conclusion that, in some way, I need to recast `myCake` variable based on what is returned in `getCake()` function. How can I do that?

**I do not want specific functions for each cake type (`getStrawberryCake()`), because I could have 50 cakes.**

Comment: Make base,frosting, etc. tio be classes with shared base, while there would be one cake to contain of them?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: you're trying to create unique classes for each variant. Don't. Instead create cake and classes for features of cake you can store... "add to cake". Then you'll have createCake, cake.addFeature(frosting).. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like the compiler to help infer the proper types for you, as opposed to having to "cast" (actually [type assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)) in multiple places, then it can be done by changing a few things in your code.

The first thing is that the compiler does not understand that `Chocolate`'s `frosting` property is always the exact string `"chocolate"`, because you've annotated it as `string`.  To give it a better idea of the relationship between `frosting` and the type of cake, you can mark the properties as `readonly` and don't annotate at all.  This prompts the compiler to infer that `"chocolate"` is a [string literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) which can be used later to key off of a mapping from cake frosting names to class types:

```
class Chocolate extends Cake {
  readonly frosting = "chocolate"
  cut() {
    console.log("cut to 8 pieces!")
  }
}
```

And the same goes for `Strawberry`:

```
class Strawberry extends Cake {
  readonly frosting = "strawberry"
  topping: string = "coconut"
}
```

Then we'll do a little type juggling to give names to the mapping from frosting to class type:

```
type PossibleCakes = Chocolate | Strawberry;
type CakeMap = { [K in PossibleCakes["frosting"]]: Extract<PossibleCakes, { frosting: K }> };
// type CakeMap = { chocolate: Chocolate; strawberry: Strawberry; }
```

The `PossibleCakes` type is just the union you were using, and you can always add members to this union as desired.  The `CakeMap` uses a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) whose properties use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) to pull the proper member out of the `PossibleCakes` union. This ends up becoming the equivalent of `{chocolate: Chocolate; strawberry: Strawberry;}`.

Now we can finally write the `getCake()` function.  It should be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function so that by calling it with a particular `frosting` value, the output will be a *particular* class, not the `PossibleCakes` union.

Here it is:

```
function getCake<K extends keyof CakeMap>(frosting: K, myName: string): CakeMap[K] {
  return { chocolate: new Chocolate(myName), strawberry: new Strawberry(myName) }[frosting];
}
```

First let's look at the signature... the `frosting` parameter is of type `K`, a generic type variable constrained to `keyof CakeMap` which in this example is `"chocolate" | "strawberry"`.  If you call `getCake("chocolate", "xxx")` the value of `K` should be inferred as `"chocolate"`.  Then the return type is `CakeMap[K]`, which is what you get when you [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the `K`-keyed property of `CakeMap`.  If `K` is `"chocolate"`, then `CakeMap[K]` is `Chocolate`.

Notice that I've changed the implementation significantly into a straightforward object lookup. That is partially just stylistic choice, but mostly it's because the compiler can actually verify that the output of that will be a `CakeMap[K]`, because the object is a `CakeMap` and the index is a `K`.  The iterative version with `Object.keys()` and `forEach()` is not as conducive to compiler inference.  If you stick with that version, you'll likely need a type assertion somewhere.

Anyway, let's see if it works:

```
const myCake = getCake("chocolate", "John")
console.log(myCake.frosting)
console.log(myCake.myName)
myCake.cut()
```

No errors anymore.  `myCake` is known by the compiler to be `Chocolate` and therefore the `cut()` method is known to be available.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYGsCm0DeAoa0C2BPAcmNkgFzQQAuATgJYB2A5gNybQBGkp519D0AvNABEANzB0aIcENYAzKgHtKvMpVqMBwpNgAOFXDKzAFdNQFdgFBVQAUeQsVU9GASjSssFABY0IAOnsiFEFA4lYAX3RI9FBIGFgvBWNwChQkAA9UugATeMQUDCwqJDBskxBcaHklCl5NIWBE5LBUw2hgMwobN0KsdpMIBRAkPxAFBhsGzugraAAOaB0aJGAkCABCIRcIqPQY8ChoAGVqMAB3NiQqKkqMrNy4fPcikrK6CqrFZQ1BITVzy7XAysKw6JaMJzqPi-YzGOidGTRfQ6FAABSUEBobGG8GQMEECSSQxaKAAPsdThcrjcWMiULikABZMA6TSoaAAbQA0tB6NB0VAsTj8hAOUJqt8GEIALrSsgAUUyVDAlgAPALMdikAyIAAaNCfGoqaA88IAPmg4RYAHprTNcCjHshmazBOzGkSUlxCc1UkxuMqqUCyCdA4CaZa9raqmY6JYaAN0LJY-GTNAGEgKAzVTy7kgcjBkLgFLInUyWWabBLahCTfrQlw1LwXGQGS7udLntBihQzFQ6AaPb6uHQkGc4E1iak7AQgi59f8gzcyKPx6GAdTcDOHEg3OEOdXeNKWNFo2MGDRgDEBhQcLgGZoM1n8pMh1OkEJ9UIAFIKLx0LZr1MIYRnPGcGT8Q9XCAwZhlGcZwPyAJZ2IbY8AgjoujcIA)

Comment: Very elegant solution, I love it! This has been very informative. I have also further extended the solution with adding `type PossibleFrosting = keyof CakeMap`, and how to handle it if the frosting value is coming from an API call. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=38&pln=24&pc=1#